# Trouble with BLE android

Tags: java, android

I'm making an application for android. This app must scan to devices and then connecting to its. I've taken a code on GitHub because I never worked with it.
App have compiled but doesn't scan and connect with any devices. Please help and if you can explain me, how this program works I would be very happy... and sorry for my English. 
Application:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

Answer (score 0):

This application detect Bluetooth LE, and as stated in the Wikipedia page :

> Bluetooth Low Energy is not backward-compatible with the previous (often called "classic") Bluetooth Basic Rate/Enhanced Data Rate (BR/EDR) protocol

So make sure you are running your tests with a compatible device.

Comment: I use a nRF52. it supports BLE

Comment: Have you search in the issues ? https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt/issues Your response may be here.

Comment: Excuse me, i don't understand. Could you explain?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I see

Answer (score 0):

That sample is like four years old and is not in line with the new Marshmallow permission requirements that the user must be shown a popup at runtime. If you merge https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt/pull/20 into your code I guess it should work.

Answer (score -1):

When we copy the code from git hub u can just create your own activity with the same name so all the properties match with your environment, and then paste it from the copied project parallelly.

Comment: the point is that Android Studio doesn't show anything error. App just is running and all. I can press button etc. but don't work.